# How do I type an array of CallableFunction's that might be async?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```js
export const provide = async (callables: CallableFunction[]) => {
    for (const callable of callables) {
        await callable()
    }
}
```

A `callable` may or may not be async.

I've tried typing it like this:

```js
export const provide = async (callables: CallableFunction[] | Promise<CallableFunction>[]) => {
    for (const callable of callables) {
        await callable()
    }
}
```

But vscode gives me the error:

> This expression is not callable.
> No constituent of type 'CallableFunction | Promise' is callable.

How do I type an array of CallableFunction's that may or may not be async?

Comment: A CallableFunction is a callable function, which may or may not contain the async keyword. They return void.

Comment: @Jdion84 If `CallableFunction` is the built in type, then it already includes functions which return promises. So you should just need your first code: `(callables: CallableFunction[])`. Did that not work for some reason? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7zFCA3AlgE2DgF44BDVAT2QTgAoEyAbJsgIyeFQC44BhZqw7AAYgFcaMXCgDaAXQCUJAHxwA3gCg42uADNo9JGniMW7TnAi7Eg81yWadT8gHcyuE7eF0FWnQF8NQI0jdBszYR5+L05xSWlkeRI4GT9tHxV1fwAaNPIqGnolYlU1QLkNDUwcAmAGGPsNIA)

Comment: @NicholasTower it works, but I want to be able to see that it could be a promise when hovering over the argument type in vscode. This is purely for DX purposes and code maintainability.

Comment: Ah, then CallableFunction is not a good choice. It includes `any` as the return type, which is bad for maintainability. Mulan's latest suggestion (which they edited into their answer) is what i would recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CallableFunction` includes any would-be `async` functions -

```
const provide = async (callables: CallableFunction[]) => {
    for (const callable of callables) {
        await callable()
    }
}
```

```
provide([
    () => { console.log("hello") },
    async () => { 
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))
        console.log("world")
    },
])
```

```
hello
world
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxANwJYBMCmMC8MCGEAnmMDABTD4A21+ARtZhAFwwDCNdjmAYgK6koqcAG0AugEpcAPhgBvAFAwVMAGYgEFUJFhVaDJjBBqY+7kwjSlq2wQDu+VHq6HM5SctUBfRb8WIKBjuol4qHrIKZuAQIEwAdNQgAObkAEQAFpi0IGnS3gA0YQTEpBTSOHLyMMW2+I7OMGCY9jAACkgAtqgQ7lqVML1QACqonZgg-FDkCAUwAIwADMuSnnaqOrEJSalp9prU6HnFhYpSQA)

---

According to your comment, it sounds like the `CallableFunction` interface is not suitable for your needs -

```
const provide = async (callables: Array<() => void | Promise<void>>) => {
    for (const callable of callables) {
        await callable()
    }
}
```

Now you can see a more explicit type -

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know it works but I want to see, when hovering the argument type, that the function could return a promise.

Comment: @jdion84 then you need to declare a more specific type for `callables`. maybe `CallableFunction` interface is too generic?

Comment: The callables all return void. I guess I can just do it that way.

Comment: @jdion84 see my update for a suggestion

Answer (score -1):

Generally, instead of typing functions with CallableFunction, we type them like this: `((...) => ...)` as you can see in the typescript documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions

Since asynchronous functions return a Promise, the type "any" will fit for them too.

This is how you can fix it:

```js
export const provide = async (callables: (() => any)[]) => {
    for (const callable of callables) {
        await callable()
    }
}
```

Comment: Using “any” is the exact opposite of what I’m trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Your "provide" arrow function seems to be a helper reusable function that can be called from anywhere in your application without considering the context, so the (() => any) type can fit there very well. But the CallableFunction can be used in this situation as well, since the CallableFunction also does not specify params and return types.